# Java Spring - Endpoint will "schedule" a method to run after X minutes but it should be able to abort this run, is it possible?

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I was thinking of adding a sort of Lock mechanism to my web application.

So the ideia would be they would enter "Edit mode" this would be realyed to my backend.
Afterwards I would start a timer (should be 30 minutes but for now let's do 30 seconds to better test this).

After this first timer is done, I would then want to communicate with frontend (a method I already have it) and start a second timer(2 minutes, but it can be 15 seconds here). If the user answers (it would be through sockets or kafka) then I would want to restart the initial timer.
Otherwise communicate with frontend that edit mode is off for that user, since he timed out.

Is this even possible?

PS: there are multiple edit mode pages

So an idea would be:

```
GetMapping(String id) {
    create "scheduled" task to run warnUser() after 30 minutes associated with this id somehow
}

warnUser(String id) {
    communicate with frontend (this part I can handle) via kafka/sockets that user should respond
    create "scheduled" task to run kickUser() after 2 minutes associated with this id somehow
}

kickUser(String id) {
    communicate with frontend to kick user with id from edit mode
}

extendTimer(String id) {
    If frontent communicate with me, then start 30 minute timer for warnUser() again
}
```